# Cannot load images in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I cannot load static images. Did I miss anything here?

Here is my servlet xml file

**servlet.xml**

[image]

**Project structure**

[image]

And this is on my page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your resources folder from WEB-INF into WebContent folder.

It should be at the same level as WEB-INF folder, not inside it.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I thought it should be inside the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: Nah in your WEB-INF are configuration files, it is blocking the resources due to security stuff. You are welcome bro.